# A cat and a dog, a dollar store Lucky Luke and... Sebastian from The Little Mermaid

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Looking for a bizarre collection of cartoons that are part of *one* cartoon, playing back to back, each having their own segment. The segments I remember (not sure if there are more):

**Sebastian** - it centers around Sebastian from The Little Mermaid. I don't remember much about this one.

**Cat and Dog** - a cat and a dog living in a house hold together and messing with each other. There are two episodes I remember: one is about the cat dying and being judged in heaven (there is one scene where a different cat is sent to hell by being thrown through an opening in a wall), the other is about a thunderstorm, where the cat and dog are both frightened, I think.

**Marsupilami** - This one is really weird. It has what looks like a Marsupilami, but it can talk and his tail is useless. Also he hangs around with a big animal, probably a gorilla or something, can't really remember.

**Lucky Luke Like** - Unlike the other segments, this one is the only one that has a multi-episode story with cliffhangers at the end of each episode. It centers around this Lucky Luke looking guy, who chases after a trio (?) of robbers. Unlike Lucky Luke though, he's *really* lame and fails at his job, getting his ass kicked pretty much always up until the end, when the robbers are finally stopped. In fact, I remember how he got punched by the big buff dude in the first episode, whose fist is almost as wide as the Lucky Luke guy is tall. He gets knocked back pretending to not be hurt at first, then collapses. Other things I remember is a really small guy (maybe a mouse?), who was used as a matchstick for some reason, lost his head as a result I guess, but didn't die, then was eaten alive at some point, leaving behind only his bones.

Does anyone know about that cartoon series?

Some more details:

- I think it aired late 90's and/or early 2000's.
- I saw it in Switzerland on a German-speaking channel, but I don't know which channel.

Comment: What about this series is science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: I'm a bit torn about the SFF elements, but I'm still voting to leave open, if only for the hell/heaven part.

Comment: Sebastian from the Little Mermaid is a fantasy character.  A cat and dog are fantasy characters if they behave like humans and talk.

Comment: Are you seriously going to fuss over details like that when one of the cartoons is about a talking crab?

Comment: Related Meta discussion: [Are anthropomorphic animals by themselves enough to deem a work fantasy?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5119/98028) Long story short: _we would consider talking animals to be part of a fantasy if: 1/ They had been uplifted in some way (either by technology or magic) 2/Their speaking was somehow fantastical to the other characters._

Comment: @Jenayah But that talking crab comes from the same universe as The Little Mermaid, which has, as the name _might_ suggest, mermaids, also has a god like being with a magical trident, sea witches, and... do I need to go on? Are those still not enough?

Comment: As said above, from where _I_ stand it's on-topic. I can't speak for others, though. I merely linked the Meta to clarify things for people who'd be unsure, or just curious about what our scope is :)

Comment: @Jenayah Fair enough, sorry if I sounded aggressive.

Answer (score 3):

I have little knowledge of Disney cartoons of that era but did some research.

> A series of shorts starring Sebastian were aired as part of the Disney animated series Marsupilami.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Mermaid_(1989_film)[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Mermaid_(1989_film))

Marsupilami had a segment with a dog and a cat left alone in their house by their humans in each episode.

> There were 13 episodes in the series, which lasted one season and ended on December 11, 1993. Reruns of the show were aired on The Disney Channel (from October 1994[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami_(1993_TV_series)) to June 1995[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami)), and later on Toon Disney. Each of the 13 episodes would feature one new "Marsupilami" short, then one short either featuring Sebastian the Crab or Shnookums and Meat, and then an old "Marsupilami" short, from "Raw Toonage". The old short "Wanna Be Ruler" isn't part of this series.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami_(1993_TV_series) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami_(1993_TV_series))

Having no knowledge of Lucky Luke, I have no idea of how much the Marsupilami segment resembled Lucky Luke.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsupilami)

Comment: Yeah, was going to say, pretty sure the only cartoon with Marsupilami was Marsupilami. Although sometimes short cartoons get recut into a new show when brought to foreign counties, so there's a possibility it might be something unique to Switzerland also.